# Wamp url rewrite issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, wamp

My url is

`http://localhost/site.in/names-in.php?loc=kochi`

My required url is

`http://localhost/site.in/names-in/kochi`

I have this in `.htaccess` which unfortunately not working.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule names-in/(.*)/ names-in.php?loc=$1
```

I have this in page `print_r($_GET);` which shows empty array. Any inputs why its not working?

Answer (score 2):

Your original RewriteRule is not being met. You can achieve this using `{QUERY_STRING}` instead:

```
RewirteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} loc=(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /names-in/%1 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Then to internally rewrite the URL:

```
RewriteRule ^/names-in/([^/]*) /names-in.php?loc=$1 [L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache ***before*** testing this. This is using `R=301` which is a permanent redirection, I advise you change this to `R=302` while testing, as this is temporary.

I've also added `?` onto the end of the rewritten URL. This is to stop the original query appearing on the end of the URL.

Comment: Unfortunatly its throwing `500 - Internal server error`

Comment: Do you have anything else in your `.htaccess`? Or just this rule?

Comment: Nothing, just this

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've made an edit as I'd forgotten to add the `[NE]` flag the the rewrite rule. Try now.

Comment: Thx for your time, unfortunately I am still getting 500 error

Comment: I've made a further update to the original code and also included an internal rewrite which should hopefully fix the Internal Server Error.

Comment: The internal server error was due to a typo in the first line of your answer. Now the page is showing up, but query param is still showing as empty array. Might be due to some settings in my server. I will try to find a diffrent different approach. I am upvoting this, thanks for your efforts..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^names-in/(\d+)*$ ./names-in.php?loc=$1

#RewriteRule ^names-in/(.*)$ ./names.php.php?loc=$1
```

you can access from http://localhost/site.in/names-in/kochi

Comment: try printing `print_r($_REQUEST)`

Comment: Is site.in folder name ?

Comment: Yes, it is under localhost root

Comment: I have updated code, Can you try again with above code

Comment: still empty array ` Array ( )`